Initialization of Property Wrapper in Custom View Initializer
I have a data model (that is @Observable) that I want to plug into SwiftUI, preferably in something as easy as a property wrapper. Due to the (current) requirement of using a view property's value in the initializer for the property wrapper for another, I had to create a custom initializer for the child view. Looking at the pattern I have, I'm mostly curious:

Is this an ok use of property wrappers? Meaning is it ok to have it defined on the view, and then initialize a new version in the view's initializer?
I assume that all of this is on the MainActor, would this be something computationally light enough for that?

Model
@Observable
class DataService {
    var items: [String: any Equatable] = [:]
    // Other collections and methods
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    @Entry var dataService: DataService = DataService()
}

Property Wrapper
@propertyWrapper
struct DataItem<T>: DynamicProperty {
    @Environment(\.dataService) var dataService
    @State var id: String

    var wrappedValue: T? {
        return dataService.items[id] as? T
    }

    init(id: String = "") {
        self.id = id
    }
}

Root View
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var dataService: DataService = DataService()
    
    var body: some View {
        DataView(id: "test")
            .environment(\.dataService, dataService)
    }
}

Child View
struct DataView: View {
    var id: String
    @DataItem var dataItem: SomeEquatableStructOrObservedObject?
    
    init(id: String) {
        self.id = id
        self._dataItem = DataItem(id: id)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if let dataItem {
            Text(dataItem.id)
        } else {
            Text("Loading...")
        }
    }
}

